# How to check carbon frame for cracks

Tags: frames, carbon, crack

Yesterday, a little boy hit my carbon framed road bike with his little bike while I was already standing. He was not very fast, the normal 'little-boy-dreaming-on-his-bike'-speed. So, nobody got hurt, but his mum wanted me to check the frame, she was very sorry and apologized hundreds of times.
After a first look, I can not see any visible cracks or something.

Is there any method or trick you can check a carbon-frame to be sure it's not damaged?
Can there even be some cracks you do not see?
(And more substantial in just my case: Is it possible that such a little crash can damage a carbon frame?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no one was hurt then you are probably good.

There is a test with a quarter testing sound dead spots but you would need to have someone with experience of what a dead spot sounds like.

I takes a bit to fracture a carbon.

[frame failure testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6APhKvaW6ig)

[fork and hammer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QNRpSkTGoA)

Comment: Make a ring with your thumb and index and flip the nail of your index against the incriminated spot. If the sound is sharp and hollow it's OK. if it sounds dull and flat there might be a crack.

Comment: Thanks guys for this tips, I will try it and hope the best!